# Authorization required error during braintree integration in swift

Tags: ios, swift, authorization, token, braintree

I am trying to integrate braintree payment method in my swift code, but I am stuck in here, it is breaking with an error

> {"error":{"statusCode":401,"name":"Error","message":"Authorization Required","code":"AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED"}}

I have doing exactly the same as mentioned in braintree documentation. I don't know which authorization it is demanding, I do have a authorization token assigned to user when he/she logins, I am wondering if it is demanding that authorization token, but there is no such parameter in this code where I should place that token to generate client's token for payment method. Here the print statement when exeuted gives me this in log, "client Token is :

> {"error":{"statusCode":401,"name":"Error","message":"Authorization Required","code":"AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED"}}", I am bit confused in its calling also. I have just started these thing so I am very sorry I have done any obvious mistake. Thanks.

```
        // TODO: Switch this URL to your own authenticated API

        let clientTokenURL = NSURL(string: "https://braintree-sample- 
         merchant.herokuapp.com/client_token")!
        let clientTokenRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: 
         clientTokenURL as URL)
        clientTokenRequest.setValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField: 
         "Accept")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: clientTokenRequest as 
          URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            // TODO: Handle errors
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

            } else {
                print("in Session")
                let clientToken = String(data: data!, encoding: 
              String.Encoding.utf8)!
                print("Client Token is : \(clientToken)")

            }

            }.resume()
         }
```

Comment: full disclosure: I work at Braintree. For additional assistance I would recommend reaching out to Braintree Support.

Based off of your code snippet alone there are many reasons why you could be getting this exception. In order to fully assist you I would recommend contacting Support so we can review your account and our logs. One thing I do see is that you are retrieving a client token from our example app, which may be conflicting with your specific gateway since the client token won't match the gateway making the request.

I would recommend contacting Support for additional assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One have to give authorization token in headers to avoid this error. Rather than that, this version of code will work fine.

```
       completionHandler:@escaping (_ response: NSDictionary?, _ error: Error?) - 
         > ()) {



        var headers: HTTPHeaders

        // pass the authToken when you get when user login
        let authToken = getAuthorizationToken()

        if(self.isValidString(object: authToken as AnyObject)) {
            headers = ["Authorization": authToken,
                       "Content-Type": "application/json",
                       "Accept": "application/json"]

         } else {
             headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
         }

        AF.request(apiURL, method: .get, parameters: params as? Parameters, 
        encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON 
    { 
           response in
            self.handleResposne(response: response) { (response, error) in
                completionHandler(response, error)
            }
        }
     }
```